# event.preventDefault doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I'm not sure why, but for some reason an `event.preventDefault()` call isn't working in Firefox. I'm using it to block clicking on an `a` link re-directing you to the `href` and instead run a click function. Markup as follows:

jQuery:

```
$('.sub-list-click a').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();

    var sub = $(this).parent("li").next(".sub, .homepage-sub");

    if (sub.css('display') == 'none') {

        $(".sub, .homepage-sub").slideUp();
        $(".sub, .homepage-sub").children("li").animate({
            opacity: "0"
        }, 10);               

        setTimeout(function() { 
            sub.slideDown();                  
        }, 200);
        setTimeout(function() {
            sub.children("li").animate({
                opacity: "1"
            }, 200); 
        }, 500);   

    } else {
        sub.slideUp();
    }      

    return false;
});
```

It works in every other browser I've tested, just Firefox seems to be having some issues.

Comment: I expect you need to pass in `event` as an argument: `$('.sub-list-click a').click(function(event) {`.

Comment: Nevertheless, `return false;` replaces both `event.preventDefault();` and `event.stopPropagation();`, so just remove `event.preventDefault();`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add event as a parameter in your click function handler like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sub-list-click a').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var sub = $(this).parent("li").next(".sub, .homepage-sub");

        if (sub.css('display') == 'none') {
            $(".sub, .homepage-sub").slideUp();
            $(".sub, .homepage-sub").children("li").animate({
                opacity: "0"
            }, 10);

            setTimeout(function () {
                sub.slideDown();
            }, 200);
            setTimeout(function () {
                sub.children("li").animate({
                    opacity: "1"
                }, 200);
            }, 500);

        } else {
            sub.slideUp();
        }
    });
});
```

Also note that this example is wrapped inside a document.ready event (you might already do this, but since it was not apparent i'll add this as note)

"Working" example here (that prevents the following to the link, not any of the animation stuff):
http://fiddle.jshell.net/79uuqmho/1/

**Edit/Update:**
The reason why it does not work in Firefox is because using event.something gives you an event not defined error which stops the execution of your script. Chrome on the other hand does not give that exception (probably due to event being defined somewhere in the window object) and allows the script to execute down to return false; (which is the same as {event.preventDefault(); /* AND */ event.stopPropagation();}

Comment: Note that event don't need to be named event, you can call it e, ev or whatever you wish :)

Comment: Ah yes, sorry removed it after initial posting. The two reasons why i removed it is 1: event.preventDefault() does what you wanted to do, so returning false is not neceserray. Secondary, return false also stops event propagation, that is "event bubbling", if you want it to stop both the default action of the event AND to stop the event from "bubbling down" in the DOM tree you can either call return false; or event.preventDefault(); AND event.stopPropagation();. However if you only want it to stop the link from moving the user to another site preventDefault() does only that and nothing more

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ruysoyjz/2/ <- demo of the long comment i posted above (had only 4 chars left to type it with :P)

Comment: I have already told in question comments what `return false;` does, but yes: my question _prefer using event.preventDefault(); to return false;_  sounds a little incorrect. The main idea of my question was whether **you** know what `return false;` does or not :) By the way, it is "bubbling up", not "down".

Comment: True, the wording is to "bubble up", (i am sorry, i was so focused on writing a demo i forgot you said you know what it does :P) but for someone who are not used to work with event driven GUI it might be hard to understand that bubbling up means traversing "downwards" in your GUI (or towards the control-trees root). That's why i used quotation marks around it (and again, i was so into building a demo, i thought i had already named it bubble up once, it seems i had not :))

Comment: I have added an edit/update to the end of the answer to why it does not work in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

use any object in your event method parameters ie:

```
$('.sub-list-click a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // other code
}
```